# FB SDK Login error after export from eclipse (because fo proguard)

Tags: android, facebook, proguard, facebook-android-sdk

I am facing error NullPointer Exception in LoginActivity Of Facebook SDK. 
Error:

```
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.logicbridge.bigrental/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:43)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:35)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:209)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:189)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readEnum(ObjectInputStream.java:1626)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:793)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1140)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1372)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1269)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1858)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Parcel.readSerializable(Parcel.java:2142)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2016)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(Bundle.java:1262)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.content.Intent.getSerializableExtra(Intent.java:4372)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-03 11:49:13.100: E/AndroidRuntime(3497):     ... 11 more
```

I have debug manually and find error in following line...

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        callingPackage = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVED_CALLING_PKG_KEY);
        authorizationClient = (AuthorizationClient) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(SAVED_AUTH_CLIENT);
    } else {
        callingPackage = getCallingPackage();
        Log.i("Login Act - fb is null ", callingPackage + " 2");
        authorizationClient = new AuthorizationClient();
        Log.i("Login Act - fb is null ", authorizationClient + " 2");
        **request = (AuthorizationClient.AuthorizationRequest) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_REQUEST);**

    }
```

that request line in else condition.
You can see LoginActiviy of Facebook [code here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/LoginActivity.java)

APK doesn't work after I export it using signed keystore file, It works without export.

I am new to Facebook SDK Implimentation I have used fb sdk of PHP in website.

Please help me I am not finding what is wrong.

Thank You.

**Edited**

I am at one stage now, after I add apply progourd it is not working, before progourd and export it than it is working.
Here is my progourd.

```
-optimizationpasses 1
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.facebook.model.** { *; }

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
-verbose
```

I am not good in progourd, So how to avoid progourd only on my DisplayAds.java activity where I place one login button and All Facebook SDK classes. Please help me.

Comment: did you identify your first issue?